# Round off Decimal Value in HTML

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I take data from Spreadsheet, So I use the below formula in App script
Now the data in spreadsheet **value=2.33344443333**
Hence in HTML same 2.33344443333 it's showing when i call **emailTemp.data**, Please help me to change to have only 2 decimal value like **2.33**

Appscript:

```
data.forEach(function(row){
  emailTemp.data=row[value];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.toFixed(2) would round a decimal value to two spaces as a string.  Presumably the following would work if you didn't need to access the value as a decimal later on:

```
data.forEach(function(row){
  emailTemp.data=row[value].toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Sry, My question is: I need to make "data" in to 2 digit decimal, not "value"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
data.forEach(function(row){
  emailTemp.data = Math.round(Number(row[value]) * 100) / 100;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I questioned wrongly,

Comment: My question is:
I need to make "data" in to 2 digit decimal not "value"